# How can i write multiple statement using conditional operator

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I am writing conditional operator in place of `if else` . But i my case i  have multiple statements as following

```
if (condition)
{
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
}
else
{
    statement 3;
    statement 4;
}
```

How could i write same using conditional operator `? and :`

Comment: This is one instance of trying to use something unnecessarily just because it's cool.

Answer (score 15):

The conditional operator is designed for evaluating alternative *expressions*, not invoking alternative *statements*.

If your two sets of statements each logically have the same result type, you *could* refactor to put each of them in a separate method:

```
var result = condition ? Method1() : Method2();
```

but if they're logically more to do with side-effects than evaluating a result, I would use an `if` block instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because the conditional operator is an expression, not a statement. You have to use an if-else construct to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Only if, for example, they expose a fluent API and have a return value (i.e. something that allows you to squeeze multiple steps into a single expression); for example:

```
sb = (someCondition) ? sb.Append("foo").Append("bar") 
        : sb.Apppend("cde").Append("fgh");
```

otherwise? no; you only get a single expression to evaluate per case. You could refactor out to methods, of course;

```
var x = (someCondition) ? MethodA() : MethodB();
```

which again assumes a return value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function or delegate that accepts a number of arguments corresponding to the number of expressions you want to evaluate:

```
int i = 7, j = 8;
Func<int, int, int> dummy = ((a,b) => b);
int k = (i < 5) ? dummy(i++, j--) : dummy(i--, j++);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", i, j, k);
```